# Apache Druid Nano Container Service Error

Tags: dockerfile, druid

I want to spin up a low configuration containerized service for which I created a Dockerfile as below:

docker build -t apache/druid_nano:0.20.2 -f Dockerfile .

---

FROM ubuntu:16.04

## Install Java JDK 8

RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY apache-druid-0.20.2-bin.tar.gz /app

RUN tar xvzf apache-druid-0.20.2-bin.tar.gz

WORKDIR /app/apache-druid-0.20.2

EXPOSE <PORT_NUMBERS>

### ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/start/start-nano-quickstart"]

When I start the container using the command "docker run -d -p 8888:8888 apache/druid_nano:0.20.2, I get an error as below:

/bin/start-nano-quickstart: no such file or directory

I removed the ENTRYPOINT command and built the image again just to check if the file exists in the bin directory inside the container. There is a file start-nano-quickstart under the bin directory inside the container.

Am I missing anything here? Please help.